# refactoring in C# codefirst

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, refactoring

I have very method is equal same

I want have one method do jobs  three or more method under

but I try use generic method or reflection but cannot write good method or class
my method:

**First method**

```
    public ActionResult _Create1(MyClassView1  content)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)            
        {
            MyClass1 Home = new MyClass1();
            Mapper.Map(content, Home);
            if (content.Id <= 0)                
                db.MyClasse1s.Add(Home);                                    
            else               
                db.Entry(Home).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Content("Ok");
        }
        return PartialView(content);
    }
```

**second method**

```
    public ActionResult _Create2(MyClassView2  content)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)            
        {
            MyClass2 Home = new MyClass2();
            Mapper.Map(content, Home);
            if (content.Id <= 0)                
                db.MyClasse1s.Add(Home);                                    
            else                
                db.Entry(Home).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Content("Ok");
        }
        return PartialView(content);
    }
```

**third method**

```
    public ActionResult _Create3(MyClassView3  content)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)            
        {
            MyClass3 Home = new MyClass3();
            Mapper.Map(content, Home);
            if (content.Id <= 0)                
                db.MyClasse1s.Add(Home);                                    
            else                
                db.Entry(Home).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return Content("Ok");
        }
        return PartialView(content);
    }
```

How can merge this class to one class?

thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method for this: [`AddOrUpdate<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520%28v=vs.103%29.aspx). But the problem is that you must find a way to supply the generic parameter `T`. Suppose you could change your view models `MyClassViewX` such that they map themselves to the entity they represent by a method `GetEntity()`. Then this is what you could do:

```
public ActionResult Create<T>(MyClassView content)
{            
    if (ModelState.IsValid)            
    {
        var entity = content.GetEntity();
        GetDbSet(db, entity).AddOrUpdate(entity);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Content("Ok");
    }
    return PartialView(content);
}

DbSet<T> GetDbSet<T>(DbContext db, T entity) where T : class
{
    return db.Set<T>();
}
```

And the method `GetEntity()`:

```
Class1 GetEntity()
{
    return Mapper.Map<Class1>(content);
}
```

This reduces the repetitive code to a number of `GetEntity` methods exactly where they belong: in the classes that know about the entity they map from and to. The `GetDbSet` takes the entity as parameter to exploit type inference which gets you to the generic type parameter `T`.

Answer (score 2):

Of the top of my head:

Create an interface `ISomething` and make your `MyClassViewX` implement that interface.

```
public interface ISomething
{
    int Id{get;}
}

public class MyClassView1 : ISomething
{
    //...
}
```

Adapt the method below to the types of your application, where `YourEntityContainerType` is the type of `db` variable and `Collection<T>` is the base type of properties of `db`: `db.MyClasse1s`, `db.MyClasse2s`...

```
public ActionResult_Create<T>(T content, Func<YourEntityContainerType, Collection<T>> collectionSelector, YourEntityContainerType db) where T:ISomething, new
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        T Home = new T();
        Mapper.Map(content, Home);
        if(content.Id <= 0)
            collectionSelector(db).Add(Home);
        else
            db.Entry(Home).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Content("Ok");
    }
    return PartialView(content);
}
```

Comment: hi 
thanks answer
but I get Error in line : db.Entry(Home).State = EntityState.Modified;
also cannot call this method buy Func (I don't understand)
and in your function content is type T and Home type is t but type content and variable Home muste be diferent

Comment: @user1928692, can you post the error? Also, can you please be more explicit (perhaps try reformatting your comment)?